# Horizontal spacing

Tags: spacing

I want to do some horizontal spacing. I tried with `\hspace{6cm}` but it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

I also tried `\\[.6cm]` but since I want to make space between two tables, it doesn't work because it needs to be written after a line, and there is no line.

Is there any other way to make some space?

EDIT: It is very hard to make an small compilable example, that's why I didn't posted it. It is a really big document to extract an SCE from it. But I'm doing the table as it follows. Perhaps that's enough clue for you to help:

```
\leftskip-1.5cm\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
Detalle      & Importe\\
\midrule
Adquisición de equipos y software  & 1574.17 \euro \\
Material inventariable &  182.45 \euro \\
Mano de obra &  8430.00 \euro TODO \\
Fungibles & TODO \euro \\                                                    
\textsc{Total} & \fbox{TODO \euro} \\
\bottomrule                
\end{tabular}
```

Problem appears then I use \hspace between 2 of these tabulars, or even between a tabular and a text line.

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) of your document.

Comment: The default behaviour when specifying `\hspace` between tables should work as expected, unless the "second table" wraps to the following line. As such, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. This includes specifying a `\documentclass`.

Comment: Note that `\hline` will only work *within* `tabular` and not *between* or *outside*.

Comment: Sorry, I meant \hspace. Already corrected it

Comment: Are you sure you want *horizontal* space? You want two tables next to each other, with additional space between them? Or are you trying to get *vertical* space, i.e. one table under the other, with additional space between it? That would explain why you tried `\\[1cm]`.

Comment: ... OK, I'm a dumb ass. That's why I didn't understand Peter's answer. So sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a compilable [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem, it is difficult to know what the exact issue is. But using `\hspace` between tables works are expected as the code below illustrates:

[image]

The `geometry` package below was used with the `showframe` option to show where the table is with respect to the margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\hspace*{1.0cm}% suppress spurious space that would otherwise gets inserted here
\begin{tabular}{|c c|}
  table 1 left & table 1 right
\end{tabular}
\hspace*{1.0cm}% suppress spurious space that would otherwise gets inserted here
\begin{tabular}{|c c|}
  table 2 left & table 2 right
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\noindent` and a couple of `%` are needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're after adding horizontal space between columns of a table, this is achieved by defining it along with the `tabular` column specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{eurosym}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eurosym
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{4cm}}r}
  \toprule
  Detalle      & Importe\\
  \midrule
  Adquisición de equipos y software  & 1574.17 \euro \\
  Material inventariable &  182.45 \euro \\
  Mano de obra &  8430.00 \euro TODO \\
  Fungibles & TODO \euro \\                                                    
  \textsc{Total} & \fbox{TODO \euro} \\
  \bottomrule                
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Using `@{<stuff>}` you can specify what should occupy the space between two columns (or at the left/right ends of the table). I've used `@{\hspace{4cm}}` to specify a `4cm` gap between the columns. Alternatively, you could also have used a column specification `lp{4cm}r` and added an extra column between the existing two, and not use it to typeset anything. However, then the gap would be slightly larger than `4cm`, since it includes some default column separation (`\tabcolsep`) on either side.

If your motivation for stretching the table is because you want it to fit in the width of the text block, then I'd suggest using the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). It specifies a column type `X`, which stretches to whatever width you specify as a mandatory argument to the `tabularx` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{eurosym}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eurosym
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
  \toprule
  Detalle      & Importe\\
  \midrule
  Adquisición de equipos y software  & 1574.17 \euro \\
  Material inventariable &  182.45 \euro \\
  Mano de obra &  8430.00 \euro TODO \\
  Fungibles & TODO \euro \\                                                    
  \textsc{Total} & \fbox{TODO \euro} \\
  \bottomrule                
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The use of `>{..}` is required to push the column entries flush right. This functionality is provided by the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array), already loaded by `tabularx`.